# Brand new Mac won't let another user with admin rights run an update for a program that came on the system

Tags: software-update, administrator

When it was originally set up, I set it up with our dept login and ran all updates.  The user has admin rights but is unable to sign into the App Store with her account for a program that has an update.  This is not a special program as it came with the system.  How do I get around this?

Comment: What's the program?  I am presuming one of the old *iLife* ones like iPhoto or something?  These are tied to the Apple ID of the person that registered them when the machine setup was completed.

Comment: I don't remember what the name of it was.